# Is there an alias that can be used in place of "expect(page).to" in RSpec and Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm still using the old RSpec 2 syntax that looks like this:

`page.should have_text('foo')`

Rather than

`expect(page).to have_text('foo')`

If say the `should` syntax becomes unsupported entirely, is there any way to build some kind alias so that I can still  use the old syntax? Basically mapping `page.should` to `expect(page).to` and `page.should_not` to `expect(page).not_to`?

I think I just have a strong affinity to the old syntax in terms of readability/cleanliness of syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to monkey patch something this this method that seems pretty straightforward:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/dba67987c63f551d1bf0f7877f069fa8b72d0461/lib/rspec/expectations/syntax.rb#L43:L45

```
def should(matcher=nil, message=nil, &block)
  ::RSpec::Expectations::Syntax.warn_about_should_unless_configured(::Kernel.__method__)
  ::RSpec::Expectations::PositiveExpectationHandler.handle_matcher(self, matcher, message, &block)
end
```

But which object exactly to monkey patch? Hard to tell, because `page` has this method, and `current_scope` has it as well, the former being the object of `Capybara::Session` class and the latter `Capybara::Node::Document`. What other possible objects get this `should` method from that module?

So, to do it properly you'd need to have very good knowledge of the Rspec and Capybara internals. When you understood it - you need to stay up to date with any future developments of this project that might influence this feature (that you are now responsible for maintaining). And if it's a commercial project - developers might find it awkward and push towards the official syntax anyway.

So it's not just a simple alias that would work forever, it's a feature to maintain. I'm not claiming it's not worth it, but you need to answer this question yourself: is it?